# paraview-julia-ubuntu on windows Triangles

Tags: ubuntu, julia, windows-subsystem-for-linux, paraview

I installed ubuntu and wsl to my windows computer. after that ı tried to install Julia and paraview. In this way I can use FLOWUnsteady codes. I did every steps given from installation manual from FLOWUnsteady web page.

When I write paraview to the Ubuntu, I get an error like this:

> Loguru caught a signal: SIGSEGV , and also, ERROR: failed process: Process(`paraview '--data=temp_vtk_example.vtk;'`, ProcessSignaled(11)) [0]

On the other hand, when I write paraview.exe to the ubuntu, paraview 5.9.1 running clearly. What should I do for connecting all of the necessary programs (julia-paraview-ubuntu)?